# PollerMetadata is null, when we use custom pollerMetadata in @InboundChannelAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I implement custom message source for pulling data. And when I run my application bean `PollerMetadata` doesn't have time to initialize before `@InboundChannelAdapter` and throws exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for channel-adapter 'statusFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0', and no default poller is available within the context.

**My code:**

```
@Bean("myTrigger")
public PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger() {
    PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(2000);
    trigger.setFixedRate(true);
    return trigger;
}

@Bean("myPollerMetadata")
public PollerMetadata currentRackStatusLandingFlowPollerMetadata(@Qualifier("myTrigger") PeriodicTrigger trigger) {
    PollerMetadata metadata = new PollerMetadata();
    metadata.setTrigger(trigger);
    metadata.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(1);
    return metadata;
}

@InboundChannelAdapter(poller = @Poller(value = "myPollerMetadata"))
public MessageSource<List<Status>> statusSource() {
    return () -> new DefaultMessageBuilderFactory()
            .withPayload(statusService.getCurrentStatuses())
            .build();
}
```

**My question:**

How to set up a `PollerMetadata` for `@InboundChannelAdapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your exception, the story is not about that `@InboundChannelAdapter`, but something like `IntegrationFlows.from(statusSource())`.

In that case you need to configure a poller on the DSL definition:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow yourFlow(PollerMetadata myPollerMetadata) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(statusSource(), e -> e.poller(myPollerMetadata))
```

The `@InboundChannelAdapter` annotation does not make sense for the Java DSL and `IntegrationFlow` definition.